# is there a way to get all template names and all package names?

Tags: theme, design, package

I am curious to know if there is any function to get all themes and all package names of magento? I know about how to get the current one, wanted to show user all the packages and all the templates. is that possible? I know that by `scandir` I can have the names by scanning the folders in `Mage::getBaseDir('design')` but wanted to know if there exists any function which I do not know of and return all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you might know, you can change the package of a product in the backend.

[image]

And when you check the attribute `custom_design` you can find the source model: `core/design_source_design` which is `\Mage_Core_Model_Design_Source_Design`. `\Mage_Core_Model_Design_Source_Design::getAllOptions` is doing what you want.